# onload event not firing in IE9 if register event when readyState is loading

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I try to place multiple images in my HTML, and manipulate them when they are all loaded.

But onload event is not firing in IE9 sometimes.

I set some console debug message, and found that if the readyState of image is loading when I register onload event, onload event will not fire.

Code snippet is as follows:

```
var loaded = function () {
    // increate counter to make sure all images are loaded or not
};

var thumbnails = $('img');
thumbnails.each(function () {
    console.log('this.readyState:'+this.readyState)

    if (this.complete) {
        loaded();
    } else {
        this.onload = loaded;
    }
});
```

P.S. I don't want to use window.onload method, because my script may be a plugin, it will be insert someone's page.

Answer (score 1):

try re-assigning the image source (src) to trigger the event, like:

```
var thumbnails = $('img');
thumbnails.each(function () {
    var img = $(this);
    console.log('this.readyState:'+this.readyState)

    if (this.complete) {
        loaded();
    } else {
        this.onload = loaded;
    }
    img.attr('src', img.attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I create a image object(new Image()), and assign the thumbnail's path to it, then register load event to fix the problem. But I don't know why cause this problem.
Is it browser's bug? Or I misunderstood the spec.